# How to pass parameters to Forms in Sitecore WFFM

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

Is there a way to pass custom values to a web form in WFFM?

There is a field named "**Parameters**" under the section "**MVC Specific Settings**" on "**Form**" template, setting this field by some values in the content editor and publishing, does not get transfer or populate to the `Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.FormViewModel`.

For Example:

[image: Link to view the Web Form in Content Editor]

Comment: What kind of parameters do you mean? What are you trying to do with the parameter after it would be passed?

Comment: My form requires few additional values, which would be shown on the form conditionally.As shown in the picture above, i have used the "parameters" field (which is above the "Submit" bar). But this be been returned null in the "FormViewModel.cshtml". Is there there any other way to pass values/have custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get Parameters field value manually by getting rendering datasource item and then parsing Parameters field.